# jQuery Mobile dynamically creating select menu

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, select-menu

I need to be able to add rows to a table dynamically with jQuery mobile. The rows consist of selection menus and input boxes. The code I have seems to work in pure jQuery and html but when I add the mobile stuff it stops working (the "added" select menus and input elements act as if the first row in the table is being clicked). I have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sPTqv/) here. Does anyone have suggestions? Or an explanation of why jQuery mobile is breaking my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `clone` on the `tr`, the cloned row is inserted verbatim into your DOM. In order to achieve the result you want, the new `<select>` needs to have a unique ID.

You should add some logic to ensure that the new `<select>` tag has a different ID, such as `select-choice-3`, `select-choice-4`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I created a new fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/gsATM/2/) with some logic attached. But there are still problems with the way jQuery Mobile is rendering it. Any ideas? Or is the logic bad?